# How to make the incall overlay not push the ui downwards

Tags: ios, user-interface

I have an iOS app. It works great.
Except when the user has a hotspot on or is in a call but the call app is minimised

The extended height of the status bar pushes my ui down, making part of it disappear,
at the bottom.

I want this extended bar to overlay the top of the screen and not push the ui downwards.

How do I achieve that ?

Comment: You can set your constraints in a way that e.g. The space between subviews shrinks. So your view won't get "pushed down" off the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Simplest Solution is to make sure that your view's `springs-and-struts` or `Autolayout` properties allow for compression or expansion of the view , If you have some complex UI then you can implement `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` observer.

You can handle the `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` and `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` notifications which will tell you the new size of the status bar.

If you are intent on using a transform on your view to handle resizing, you can implement -viewWillLayoutSubviews in your view controllers (probably in a common base class) to set a transform on the root view of the view controller.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(statusFrameChanged:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}

- (void)statusFrameChanged:(NSNotification*)note
{
    CGRect statusBarFrame = [note.userInfo[UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGFloat statusHeight = statusBarFrame.size.height;

    UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGRect viewRect = screen.bounds;

    viewRect.size.height -= statusHeight;
    viewRect.origin.y = statusHeight;
    self.view.frame = viewRect;
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    CGRect baseFrame = self.view.frame;
    // 548.0 is the full height of the view.  Update as necessary.
    CGFloat scale = self.view.frame.size.height / 548.0;
    [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, scale)];
    self.view.frame = baseFrame;
}
```

Comment: `viewDidUnload` is deprecated since iOS 6 ;)

Comment: @HAS: Check Updated Method.

Comment: Is there any way to make it so the view does not need resizing? I don't want to resize the view, i just don't want it to be pushed down, I have enough space in the view at the top of the screen, for the extended height of the status bar, i just want the status bar to be on top of my view, and not just directly above

Comment: Are you using `Auto layout`?

Comment: Now you have unbalanced calls :D. `viewDidDisappear` can get called multiple times in the lifecycle of a view controller. So this can/will lead to a runtime exception since you try to remove an observer that doesn't exist anymore. I suggest that you add the observer in `viewWill/DidAppear`. ;)

Comment: And you forgot to change the super call inside the method ;)

Comment: @Virussmca yes i am using autolayout

Comment: can you add image/screenshot of your view.?

Comment: Haha :D I'm sorry but you need to call `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` and `[super viewDidDisappear:animated];` respectively. But +1 anyways ;)

Answer (score 1):

I used use  `"Vertical space - Bottom layout Guide - Button"`. This way, a button I have on the bottom of the screen stays in the same place when there is an in call bar and if a different screen size is used (3.5inch or 4icnh).