# How to keep UIView's size when toggle in call status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Currently my UIViewController contains some buttons and when toggle in call status bar UIView shifts/resizes.

Is it possible to keep UIView's size and avoid any changes of frame? In my case it's fine that in call status bar will be placed over UIView.

Comment: There is already a question answering this at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871448/how-to-make-the-incall-overlay-not-push-the-ui-downwards